# Linq query without multiple joins

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get a

```
List<BONET_Website_Users>
```

where the Description of

```
BONET_Permissions == "R"
```

without doing multiple joins using linq?

My tables:

[image: a busy cat]

Is it possible?

Comment: What's wrong with joins? Is this an Entity Framework (LINQ to SQL) query or an in-memory LINQ to Objects query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var users = Context.BONET_Website_Users
     .Where(u=>u.BONET_Roles
          .Any(r=>r.BONET_ROLES_Permissions
                .Any(p=>p.BONET_Permissions.Description  == "R")))
     .ToList();
```

Don't think in term of joins, most of the time if you write a linq query with a join you're doing it wrong, just work your way through the graph as if it was a bunch of nested collections and let linq handle the query generation, you don't need to "think in SQL terms".

Comment: If you're writing a big query you should be aware of what the SQL behind the scenes is, sometimes LINQ can look nice and tidy but the SQL is highly inefficient. LINQPad is a great tool for this as you can see the SQL your LINQ generates.

Comment: Being aware of the generated SQL is not the same as thinking in SQL terms, if your LINQ code looks like SQL, you're doing it wrong. So you must consider things as a graph and think of what you want to get and restrict, not as lets just join to get everything i can think off, and then decide what to do with it later.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know why you'd want to do this without linq, but this will work assuming allUsers is of type List<BOTNET_Website_User> and it contains everything.

```
var result = new List<BOTNET_Website_User>();

foreach (var user in allUsers)
{
    if (user.BONET_Permissions == "R")
    {
        result.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Edit -- sorry, the image you posted is blocked so I can't see the tables that you posted. I was assuming this was all in-memory.

Comment: He never said he wanted to do this without using LINQ, re read his question.